# Websphere exception handling

Tags: security, jsp, error-handling, websphere, web.xml

From a security standpoint, what is the best solution to handle application errors with Websphere?

I've been thinking of creating a class that is called every time an application error is generated, log the error and display a generic error message to the users.

In PHP this can be achieved using the set_exception_handler() function. Is there something similar for websphere that could be configured in the web.xml?

I've found codes like this on the internet:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/servlet/ExceptionHandlerServlet</location>
</error-page>
```

But that would only work with "500" HTTP error codes. I really want something generic that catches everything. Something like a class that implements a certain interface which can have access to all information about the error.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also available in web.xml:

```
 <error-page>
   <exception-type>UnhandledException</exception-type>
   <location>UnhandledException.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
```

Among other places, this is used in [this WebSphere example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rweb_webxf.html). The JEE5 tutorial may also be helpful in setting this up, particularly the part about [mapping servlet exceptions](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnaeo.html#bnaet) and [creating JSP error pages](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnahe.html#bnahi).

Essentially, all of your exceptions should be wrapped in [ServletExceptions](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletException.html) and the JSP you map to should have `<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>` set at the very top of the page.